# PHP: IF statement within ForEach loop applying to subsequent entries

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, html-select

I have an IF statement to check for a specific string within a ForEach loop and if present then add 'selected' to the `<option>` output so that entry is displayed first within an HTML select box. However when the loop reaches the correct record it adds 'selected' every subsequent `<option>` record.

```
function adminFillOption($options, $input) {
$output = "";
$selected = "";
//iterate through the array
foreach ($options as $value => $desc) {
    if ($input == $desc) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    };
    //Add an option for each elemement of the array to the output
    $desc = htmlspecialchars($desc);
    $output .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$desc' $selected >$desc</option>\n";

}//end interation
return $output;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just add $selected = ''; before if statement.

Comment: Also, if you want to speed things up for end-users, avoid adding `\t` - whitespaces are cool for us humans only :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never unset it so it's set for every iteration.

Try using ternary operator to set it to nothing when the condition isn't met.

```
$selected = ($input == $desc) ? 'selected' : '';
```

or alternatively declare `$selected` in the loop, before the `if`, either would work.

So code would become:

```
function adminFillOption($options, $input) {
$output = "";
//iterate through the array
foreach ($options as $value => $desc) {
    $selected = ($input == $desc) ? 'selected' : '';
    //Add an option for each elemement of the array to the output
    $desc = htmlspecialchars($desc);
    $output .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$desc' $selected >$desc</option>\n";

}//end interation
return $output;
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/546236

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you for the answer and the information

Answer (score 0):

```
function adminFillOption($options, $input) {
    $output = "";
    foreach ($options as $value => $desc) {
        //Add an option for each elemement of the array to the output
        $desc = htmlspecialchars($desc);
        $output .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$desc'";
        if ($input == $desc) $output .= ' selected';
        $output .= ">$desc</option>\n";
    }//end interation
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because, you are assigning value to `$selected` only once (when it is selected one).

And after the selected one is reached, the variable is not getting modified.

Change

```
if ($input == $desc) {
 $selected = 'selected';
};
```

To:

```
if ($input == $desc) {
 $selected = 'selected';
}
else {
 $selected = '';
}
```

OR Even following options are better:

```
$selected = '';
if ($input == $desc) {
 $selected = 'selected';
}
```

Ternary operator:

```
$selected = ($input == $desc) ? 'selected' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function adminFillOption($options, $input) {
$output = "";
// $selected = ""; -----> not here
//iterate through the array
foreach ($options as $value => $desc) {
    $selected = ""; // ----> but here
    if ($input == $desc) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    };
    //Add an option for each elemement of the array to the output
    $desc = htmlspecialchars($desc);
    $output .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$desc' $selected >$desc</option>\n";

}//end interation
return $output;
}
```

If you do it like that the `$selected` will always be reset through each iteration